# MySQL COUNT not returning False or True in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to check if a user already liked a post.

**Code:**

```
function previously_liked($id) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
        $user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
    }
    else {
        $user = "";
    }

    $connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

    $id = $connection->real_escape_string($id);

    $query = $connection->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `count` FROM `likes` WHERE `id` = '$id' AND `user_id` = '".$connection->escape_string($user)."'");

    while ( $row = $query->fetch_object()->count ) {
            if ( $row->count == 0 ) return false;
            else return true;
}
}
```

The thing is, it's not returning false or true. On my other PHP page I'm trying to run this function like this:

```
if (previously_liked(70) === true) {
    $aliked = "You've already liked this!";
}

echo $aliked;
```

The only error I'm seeing is `Notice: Undefined variable: aliked in profile.php on line 391`

Any help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: One supposes that the query is returning an error and you should check for that.  You could probably fix it by using parameterized values rather than sticking the values directly into the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this things to finds error in your code:

```
echo $user; //before MySQL query
```

Query your MySQL statement in MySQL console or app like PHPmyAdmin after replacing ".$connection->escape_string($user)." to your user_id. If it fetch row than your MySQL statement is correct and there is something wrong with $_SESSION["user_login"] value.

Optionally, you can also echo the returning rows to check the output data.

Otherwise check your query statement as column names, table name, database etc.

Hope, it helps you...

Comment: Thanks, I also noticed that my post ID is not called ID in the database. Fixed everything now! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine, your problem is something else: You're defining `$aliked` inside the scope of the if-statement, so you can't use it outside. You need to change your code, one possibility is this:

```
if (previously_liked(70) === true) {
    echo "You've already liked this!";
}
```

or this:

```
$aliked = "";
if (previously_liked(70) === true) {
    $aliked = "You've already liked this!";
}

echo $aliked;
```

Comment: Hmm, it's still not showing anything. I know for sure that the result is true but it's not showing You've already liked this!

Comment: Fixed it by removing `->count` at the end of the `$row` in the while loop. Your answer also fixed a issue, so thanks!