# MySQL query not returning true or false

Tags: php, mysql

**I'm having some issues with this code:**

```
function previously_liked($id) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
        $user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
    }
    else {
        $user = "";
    }

    $connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

    $id = $connection->real_escape_string($id);

    $query = $connection->query("SELECT `user_id` AS `count` FROM `likes` WHERE `id` = '$id' AND `user_id` = '".$connection->escape_string($user)."'");

    if ($query->fetch_object()->count == $user) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It should check if the user already liked a post and then return `true` if the user has already liked it and return `false` if not.

The thing is, it's not returning true while the user actually did like something.

Comment: @user1717828 In the DB `user_id` is equal to `$user` (the current logged in user). I was trying to check if `user_id` was equal to `$user` and then run the code. Which obviously isn't working.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794796/mysql-count-not-returning-false-or-true-in-php/28794857#28794857

Comment: @mmgross Probably followed the same tutorial. That solution didn't fix my issue though :(